# Why am I getting 100% disk usage on Windows 10, I've tried other solutions

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, performance

How do I stop my disk usage being at 100% on Windows 10? Below is what I've tried

- Changing Link Storage Technology in Intel Rapid Storage to be off
- Restarting or Disabling Windows Search service
- Restarting or Disabling Windows Superfetch or SysMain service
- DISM and SFC scans
- Checking for hard drive errors in CrystalDiskInfo
- Running programs as administrator
- Changing the security of backup programs and high disk usage programs to give my user all the permissions in the Properties
- Looking at Task Manager to find the cause (the processes listed don't add up to 99% or 100%)

Is there any other suggestions I can do?

Here is what happens when Firefox runs in safe mode (having all extensions disabled)

[image]

Comment: If you kill firefox, ensuring that there are ZERO instances of it on the details tab, does the disk usage go back to normal?

Comment: I restarted firefox in safe mode so all the extensions should be disabled and it didn't solve the problem. Look at this. https://imgur.com/a/Neo0uRh

Comment: You did notice that the Firefox **installer** is running, as well; as the application? Is the installer "stuck", and need to be killed? Is it just trying to complete update?

Comment: Where's the installer?

Comment: Run system internals process monitor.  Add a filter `Process` -> `contains` -> `File`    and watch whatever it is spam the crap out of your hard disk.  There are many things using the disk.. you will need to figure out who isn't playing nice.  You can do this by one at a time.. seeing the unimportant stuff.. right click on the process name and exclude that process.

Comment: I can't find the process option when creating a new filter in Process Monitor. https://i.imgur.com/KwRHvWp.png

Comment: I think you mean adding a filter where `Operation` `contains` `readfile`. I tried that and it doesn't help.

Comment: I tried that and couldn't find the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I got a working solution from Ten Forums.](https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/167215-how-do-i-stop-my-disk-usage-being-100-windows-10-a.html)

> Run: Tuneup.bat - Click the link below to go to the BSOD batch repository to download and run this batch file.

[Download tuneup.bat](https://www.tenforums.com/bsod-crashes-debugging/162488-batch-files-use-bsod-debugging-post1994120.html#post1994120)

[I also provided additional tips here.](https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/167215-how-do-i-stop-my-disk-usage-being-100-windows-10-a-3.html)

Answer (score 0):

To see which applications are doing lots of I/O:

- Run Task Manager
- Go to the Details tab
- Right-click any column header and choose "Select columns"
- Place check-marks next to "I/O reads" and "I/O writes" and click OK
- Click one of these two columns twice to order by descending values,
  then the other.

Comment: Firefox is using the most resources, and enabling or disabling hardware acceleration in Firefox doesn't help.

Comment: This is not normal. You must have installed some rogue add-on, intentionally or not. You could check if this happens when you [Start Firefox in Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-extensions-themes-to-fix-problems#w_start-firefox-in-safe-mode).

Comment: Closing Firefox doesn't help make the disk usage go down, so the problem is not firefox. This also includes when there's zero instances of it on the details tab.

Comment: So what is using this I/O? Could you add a screenshot of Task Manager?

Comment: I restarted firefox in safe mode and it didn't solve the problem. Look at this. https://imgur.com/a/Neo0uRh